# Building a GUI for a small desktop application

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jsr296

I am currently working on a small desktop Java application which will track various data such as employee hours, job-site investment, and a few other things.  So far I've been able to knock out most of the stuff under the hood (serializing data, etc) but I've hit a roadblock when it comes to the front-end.

I've tried using swing: by hand, with eclipse/windowbuilder pro, and with netbeans, all with little success.  Is there another platform better suited to such a simple application?  Maybe JavaFX? Or should I just roll up my sleeves and dive into swing?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For a small application I'd suggest you to roll up your sleeves and dive into Swing.  At least you can study a lot. When you have questions come to SO, clear 'em and move forward.

Comment: *"..roll up your sleeves and dive.."** Also remove your shoes or sandals.  :)

Comment: @shamaniacal As a plus, you'll find learning JavaFX - when the time comes - to be much easier if you've got Swing experience

Answer (score 0):

If you don't like swing you may try [swt](http://eclipse.org/swt/). Eclipse UI is based on it. Take a look at the [FAQ](http://www.eclipse.org/swt/faq.php) which would give you the answers.

Comment: A few years ago the SWT documentation was far inferior to Swing's.  Have the SWT docs improved?  Otherwise I would not recommend SWT for a first project.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I think the future of the Java Desktop is with JavaFX. If you've got to dig in somewhere that could be your best bet. OTOH, Swing won't be going away soon; the tools are better; and there's probably more in the way of tutorials etc...